# What is the difference between foreign key constraint & referential integrity constraint

Tags: database, rdbms

This might be a silly question pardon me if.
I recently faced this question:

Consider the relations R1(A,B,C) and R2(B,P,Q), where A,B,C,P,Q are sets
of attributes. The values of B in R1 must mandatorily exist in R2. This is
an example of

1. a foreign key constraint
2. logical data independence
3. a referential integrity constraint
4. a domain constraint

Answer: a referential integrity constraint

I cannot distinguish between referential integrity constraint & foreign key constraint

Comment: What does the textbook/reference associated with that quiz say? What does your other research yield? What do you think those terms mean? Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Well, is "The values of B in R1 must mandatorily exist in R2" a FK constraint? PS In relational theory "referential integrity constraint" sometimes means that subrow values appear elsewhere but sometimes for that plus as superkey & sometimes plus as CK. (Either of the latter might be used to mean a FK constraint). In SQL "referential integrity constraint" can mean that NULL-free subrows appear elsewhere & sometimes plus as SQL UNIQUE (aka a SQL FK constraint) & sometimes plus as SQL PK. And in SQL it might mean a DB restriction like that has been declared.

Comment: What I understood is that in SQL, FK constraint is a subset of RE constraint i.e a RE constraint in which the referenced attributes are constraint to be unique are also FK constraint.So there is no unique constraint on B in R2 so this is just a referntial integrity constraint not FK constraint. right??

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS "no unique constraint" "so this is just a referntial integrity constraint not FK constraint" Right. PS Although we do not know the exact definitions for your quiz, that difference of uniqueness seems to let us decide. PS The quiz seems to be about the relational model, not SQL. SQL is not fully relational, SQL tables are not relations & terms don't mean the same thing in SQL as in the relational model. Including "unique". But the difference in "uniqueness" still seems to distinguish the 2 terms in your post for both the relational model & SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why we are preferring Referential Integrity Constraint:**

According to the reference[1], the referential integrity constraint is the state of a database in which all values of all foreign keys are valid.

In your example, the line “ The values of B in R1 must mandatorily exist in R2” indicates--the child table(R2) contains all values of B from the parent table(R1), means all values of B in R2 are valid -- resulting in Referential integrity constraint.

**Again why we are not using foreign key constraint:**

According to the reference[2], it is not necessary to always have foreign keys to ensure referential integrity constraints. There are other ways of ensuring the integrity constraint.

Back to your example, there is no mention about foreign keys or primary keys. The question only indicates the reference between two tables. Hence, it would be better to choose the referential integrity constraint instead of foreign key constraint.

References:

https://www.toolbox.com/tech/big-data/question/difference-between-foreign-key-and-refrential-integrity-constraint-091703/
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4242/sql-server-referential-integrity-without-foreign-keys/